# angular-material TypeError: $mdThemingProvider.backgroundPalette is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am using md-tabs and want to set the background color from the default light grey to white. In my module, I defined this:

```
var module = angular.module('myMod', ['ngMaterial']);
module.config(function ($mdThemingProvider) {
    $mdThemingProvider.backgroundPalette('white');
});
```

When I start my application, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myMod due to:
TypeError: $mdThemingProvider.backgroundPalette is not a function
```

I am using angular-material version 1.1.5.

Any ideas on why this error is occuring? Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I got it. In the module, the white color has to be defined for all shades:

```
var module = angular.module('myMod', ['ngMaterial']);
module
.config(function ($mdThemingProvider) {
    $mdThemingProvider.definePalette('white', {
        '50': 'ffffff',
        '100': 'ffffff',
        '200': 'ffffff',
        '300': 'ffffff',
        '400': 'ffffff',
        '500': 'ffffff',
        '600': 'ffffff',
        '700': 'ffffff',
        '800': 'ffffff',
        '900': 'ffffff',
        'A100': 'ffffff',
        'A200': 'ffffff',
        'A400': 'ffffff',
        'A700': 'ffffff'
    });
    $mdThemingProvider
        .theme('default')
        .backgroundPalette('white');
});
```

And the color has to be set in the respective html for the element. In my case:

```
<md-content md-colors="{'background-color': 'white'}">...</md-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the theme that you want to modify from the provider first:

```
$mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
     .backgroundPalette('white');
```

Comment: I did also try that but then I got the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '600' of undefined". Apparently, I have to define white first. Could that be?

Comment: Seems white isn't one of the predefined colors so that seems likely

Comment: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/03_configuring_a_theme seems to have the information you're after